# How can I make this JQuery code more responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flickity

I am trying to create a progress bar that adjusts based on device's width but I am having an issue.

With this specific setup, every time the device width changes, the progress bar's width doesn't, so it's not really usable if somebody switches to landscape, it breaks the site.

Just a quick note, I have 2 progress bars, one stacked on top of each other.

EDIT: Here is a working solution, check below

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_block-1545-2104" class="ct-div-block progress-bar"></div>
<div id="div_block-1545-2104" class="ct-div-block progress-bar2"></div>
```

```
$carousel.on("scroll.flickity", function (event, progress) {
    const $progressBar = $(".progress-bar");
    const divWidth = $(".progress-bar2").width();

    progress = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, progress));
    $progressBar.width(progress * divWidth);
});
```

Comment: Rory McCrossan, you had edited the code snippet, but it'll don't run. You or the question owner can be fixed.

Comment: Well it won't run because it needs and external js to work (https://flickity.metafizzy.co/). I just gave the code as a reference to see what I am trying to do.

Comment: you should really change the width via CSS but you will need to hook into the resize-event of window anyway so you might as well fix it up there too, like you're currently doing on every image scroll-flickity-event apparently .. whenever they occur.

Comment: I got confused there. Can you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Changes of width due to device properties - like landscape/portrait - should best be handled via CSS, but you need to hook into window-resize-event. You will probably want to look into [some throttle/debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) too though, since these sort of events (resize,scroll,etc.) may fire repeatedly in short order!

```
$(window).on('resize', function(e){ $progressBar.width( Math.max(0,Math.min(1,progress))*divWidth); } )
```

For clarity:

```
var $progressBar = $('.progress-bar'),
    divWidth = $('.progress-bar2').width();

$carousel.on('scroll.flickity', function(event, progress){
    console.debug( "the scroll.flickity event fired." );
} );
$(window).on('resize', function(e){ 
    console.debug( "the window:resize event fired. [throttle!!?!]" );
    progress = Math.max( 0, Math.min(1, progress));
    $progressBar.width(progress * divWidth);
} )
```

Comment: So where would that code go exactly? I am a little bit confused on what I need to change here.

Comment: wherever you hook all your events .. like inside the $( function(){ console.log( "pageLoad and eventHooks" ); } );

Comment: Oh so I hook this as a completely different function or...? I am pretty newbie with this.

Comment: what you're doing in your code was hooking into the scroll.flickity event of your carousel instance - see the documentation for that library code to understand when that fires - and in the same place (a line before or a line below) you should hook into the resize-event of the window object via the line of code I posted. You can then remove the "$progressBar.width(…)" line from your event-handler code since that doesn't do what you want. The issue with throttle/debounce is one you should be aware of, but when getting started with coding: keep it simple, keep learning and HAVE FUN! :-)

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. I think I kinda get what you mean now. I will look into the documentation and throttle I guess. I don't need to edit anything in this code right? (I could just remove the console.debug although I guess it's not needed)

Comment: lose the debug output, sure. I'd keep it though .. until you go LIVE with the project .. so you see when exactly the events do fire. debug output is one of the oldest ways to keep track of what your program is doing, sure fancy IDEs will give you break points and capabilities to watch values or even parts of memory directly - much more elegant .. but sometimes you can go with the basics just as well ;-)

Comment: There is a simplier solution to this I guess. I just had to put the vars in the function as const and everything gets adjusted perfectly without adding resizing. Check the original post for clarification.